# Trying to understand the extern keyword

Tags: c++, extern

I am trying to learn about the extern keyword.

I created this file try2.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

extern int a;

int main()
{

    a = 5;
    printf("%d", a);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And this one try1.cpp

```
int a;

int main()
{

    a = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting an error in try2.c that a is undefined. 
Both files are in the BIN folder of TurboC.

What is the problem?

Comment: This looks a whole lot like C code, why the c++ tag?

Comment: You want to build one program out of two source files, not two separate programs.

Comment: Turbo C++ from Borland was a mid-1990s and earlier compiler. That's pretty old, and in particular it predates the first C++ standard from 1998. You would do well to switch to a modern C++ compiler.

Comment: You also want to wipe TurboC off your system and install a modern compiler.

Comment: @Alf - Turbo C++ was reintroduced in the mid 2000s for a short period of time.

Comment: How are you linking them together?

Comment: Having two `main` in one program - that is the first problem

Answer (score 1):

In your `try2.cpp`, you have:

```
extern int a;
```

This tells the compiler that `a` is defined externally - i.e. not within `try2.cpp`.  So, you must actually define it externally, and to do that you need a second .cpp file - lets say you make a `a.cpp` file that contains:

```
int a;
```

You can then compile each of try2.cpp and a.cpp:

```
tc -c try2.cpp
tc -c a.cpp
```

Then you need to link them, also specifying the path to your CS.lib standard library file (search for it with Windows Explorer if the below doesn't work - updating `\TC\LIB\` path below):

```
tlink try2.obj + a.obj, program.exe, , \TC\LIB\CS.lib
```

That should create a new `program.exe` for you to run....

You should get a better compiler though....

Answer (score 0):

`extern` says that the something is defined elsewhere. You don't define it elsewhere (in this program). The linker rightly complains about that.